# Counting chain maps

Tags: vector-spaces, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and let $C_{\cdot}$ and $K_{\cdot}$ be bounded chain complexes with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$. Then the set of chain maps $f_{\cdot}:C_{\cdot}\to K_{\cdot}$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space which we denote by $W=\mathrm{Hom}_{Ch_{\mathbb{K}}}(C_{\cdot},K_{\cdot})$. In fact, if $V_{k}=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(C_{k},K_{k})$ is the space of linear maps from $C_{k}$ to $K_{k}$, then I guess $W$ should be a proper subspace of $\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{N}}V_{k}$ and hence is finite dimensional.

**Question:** What is the dimension of $W$?

My feeling is that one can determine the dimension in homological terms, but computing a basis is probably difficult.

**Update** Due to lack of response I have reposted this question at mathoverflow, you can find the post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211449/counting-chain-maps).